# Multiple nested views in UI-Router degrading performance

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am using UI-Router for my ionic application, which follows the following structure

1. Main

   - Sales - View

     - District - tab
     - Area - tab
     - Station - tab
     - Filter - tab
   - Inventory - view

     - District - tab
     - Area - tab
     - Station - tab
     - Filter - tab
   - Sourcing - view

     - Station - tab
     - Filter - tab

But when I switch views in the app then it loads filter tab and any of the remain tabs (filter & district, filter & area or filter & station). Filter tab will always be in view while you can switch between district, area and station. Now the problem is that when I switch my views i.e. From sales to inventory or inventory to sourcing, It is taking huge amount of time. I tested it in iPad Air, Samsung tab 3, still the same issue. It doesn't happen when I switch tabs.

I want to enhance the performance of the app by speeding up the time that takes to switch the view. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to resolve data before switching views?

Comment: No, I am not resolving any data. When view is changed, new data  is getting loaded.

Comment: Are you sure that the data loading isn't the cause of your slowdown?

Comment: Yes, I found the solution, I was calling two controllers at the same time. I gave timeout and it worked like a charm. Thanks for all your help.